# Unexpected token else : rewrite

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm receiving an "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else**" ... i know what the error means but I'm unsure how to fix it to work with the statement. I tried removing the `else` statement and running the `If` statement by itself but no luck. Any suggestions?

```
jQuery('.navigation_secondary-item').click(function (e) {
    if (jQuery('.box-search').hasClass('active')) {
        jQuery('.box-search').siblings().removeClass('active');
        jQuery('.box-search').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        jQuery('.box-search').siblings().removeClass('active');
        jQuery('.box-search').toggleClass('active');
    } else {
        // error here
        if (jQuery('.box-social').hasClass('active')) {
            jQuery('.box-social').siblings().removeClass('active');
            jQuery('.box-social').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            jQuery('.box-social').siblings().removeClass('active');
            jQuery('.box-social').toggleClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: use `else if` instead of multiple `else`. You can't have multiple `else` keywords in one `if` expression.

Comment: the first `else` should change to `else if`

Comment: I guess only `jQuery('.navigation_secondary-item').click(function () {
    $('.box-search, .box-social').toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});` should work.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't have more than one `else` for an `if` condition.

This should work fine for you.

```
 jQuery('.navigation_secondary-item').click(function(e){
            if(jQuery('.box-search').hasClass('active')){
                  jQuery('.box-search').siblings().removeClass('active');
                  jQuery('.box-search').removeClass('active');
                } else { 
                  jQuery('.box-search').siblings().removeClass('active');
                  jQuery('.box-search').toggleClass('active');
                } 
    // should work fine now
            if(jQuery('.box-social').hasClass('active')){
                  jQuery('.box-social').siblings().removeClass('active');
                  jQuery('.box-social').removeClass('active');
                } else {
                  jQuery('.box-social').siblings().removeClass('active');
                  jQuery('.box-social').toggleClass('active');
                }

          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `else`s coming off of one `if` :

```
if (condition) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Combine the contents of the `else` statements or reconsider your logic.